# Print integers 1-20 in groups of five per line

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting out with JS and stuck on a question which is print integers 1-20 using a while loop. Print only five integers per line.
Any help would be great!

I tried a few things, here's the latest:

```
var x=" ";
var i=1;
while (i<=20; i++) {
    x=i%5=0; "\n"
}
alert(x);
```

Comment: `Object.keys([].fill.call({ length: 20 }, 1)).map(function(i){ document.write(i + (i%5==0?'\n':'')) });` but don't use it. It's ugly ;)

Answer (score 1):

For very basic JavaScript like this, it would probably help to use a console rather than write code for a web page.  Ideally, you'd write a bunch of programs using `console.log()`, and then you'd write a bunch of programs that manipulate and generate DOM elements, and you'll entirely skip the awkward stage of `alert()` and `document.write()`.  [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) is a book that I followed in precisely this way.

In any case, here are three loops that do about what you describe.  The first is very similar to your attempt.  The other two output lines of output at a time, but differ considerably in their looping logic.

```
console.log('\nloop one')
;(function() {
  var x = '',
      i = 1
  while (i <= 20) {
    x += i
    x += i%5 ? ' ' : '\n'
    i++
  }
  console.log(x)
})()

console.log('\nloop two')
;(function() {
  var line = ''
  for (var i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
    line += i + ' '
    if (i % 5 === 0) {
      console.log(line)
      line = ''
    }
  }
})()


console.log('\nloop three')
;(function() {
  for (var i = 1, line = ''; i <= 20; line = '') {
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      line += i++ + ' '
    console.log(line)
  }
})()
```

`node example`, with the above all in a file named 'example', produces this output:

```
loop one
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20


loop two
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 

loop three
1 2 3 4 5 
6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some syntax and logic changes, like below:

```js
var i=1;
while (i<=20){
 var x=i%5; // checks for 5 numbers in a line
 
 if(x==0) 
  document.write(i+",<br>"); // give a break if 5 numbers on line
 else
   document.write(i+","); 
 i++;  

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using an array to store values of `i` , `Array.prototype.splice()`

```js
var x = []
, i = 1
, len = 5
, max = 20;

while (i <= max) {
  x.push(i++); --len;
  if (len === 0 && x[x.length - 1] !== max) {
    x.splice(x.length, 0, "\n");
    len = 5
  }
}
console.log(x);
alert(x.join(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

that's my version over here:

http://jsbin.com/pamaledopi/1/edit?js,console

Don't forget to turn F12 on! (Be sure you have console opened and click "Run")

_padEmpty is for formatting purposes, you can drop it and call to it too.